# Merging data from multiple excel files into master data file

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, powerquery

I have a data set from a reporting tool which gives 3-5 excel files, each containing around 10-12 sheets of data.

I am trying to combine all the excel files with  identical named sheets.

Sheets from excel 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AshoR.png)

Sheets from excel 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G54GI.png)

etc

- Each excel files contains similar named worksheets such as SheetABC, SheetDEF, SheetGHI etc.
- 
- I used to manually combine all SheetABC from the excel files and combine using power query, the same step for SheetDEF etc.

Is there a way to combine all the same named Sheets from different excel files into one master report and repeat the process for all the sheets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This, for example, combines all tabs from all xlsx files in a single directory

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded GetFileData",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```